# Working with files in Ansible inventory

Tags: files, configuration, ansible

This feels like it should be a really easy thing to do, but I cannot figure it out.
I am aware of several pieces of documentation outlining where Ansible is looking for files by default and most of that is fine and understood.

My Question is - plain and simple - can I - and if so how - copy a file from my Ansible inventory to a remote?

To elaborate, consider the following directory layout:

```
ansible
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   ├── group_vars
│   │   └── group1
│   │       ├── vars.yml
│   │       └── upload.txt
│   ├── host_vars
│   ├── hosts.ini
├── playbooks
│   └── staging.yml
└── roles
    └── ansible-role-upload
```

So what I want to do is the following: Run `staging.yml` which in turn calls `ansible-role-upload` to upload `upload.txt` to the remote server.

Absolute paths are no option to me.

Any input - even telling me that that is a dumb idea - is appreciated.

Comment: Use [inventory_dir](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables).

Comment: Could you please post the task you want to execute from `ansible-role-upload`?

Comment: You should post the code you've already tried. [edit] the question and make it [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the `inventory_dir` variable @VladimirBotka I will take a look at that. I do not have a current MRE because I first wanted to ask the community. I think the answer by @U880D might work, but I have a hunch that I already tried that. Will take another look with all your input and update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have a similar setup I like to answer your questions as follow.

> Can I .. copy a file from my Ansible inventory to a remote?

Yes.

> Absolute paths are no option to me.

Use relative paths. Constructs like

```
- name: Copy file(s) to remote host
  copy:
    src: ../iventory/group_vars/group1/upload.txt
    dest: /tmp
```

or

```
- name: Copy file(s) to remote host
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /tmp
  with_fileglob:
    - "../iventory/group_vars/group1/*.txt"
```

are working.